# Are AWK "commands" can also be called as "Built-in Functions"?

Tags: awk

In this [AWK cheat sheets](http://bl831.als.lbl.gov/~gmeigs/scripting_help/awk_cheat_sheet.pdf), I find the `print`, `printf`, etc are named as `commands`, while `gsub`, `index` are named as `Built-in String Functions`. My question is, are these `commands` can also be called as `Built-in Functions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, `printf "format", values` is **statement**, as well as `print`. You can call them commands if you like. The function in awk has format: `functionname(arg1,arg2..)` and usually has a return value.

E.g.  statement `3 + gsub(....)` would be `3+ result of a function call`, we cannot do `"foo" print "bar"` or `3 + printf "%d",5`

So I wouldn't say `printf and print` are built-in **Functions**.